# User ASP.NET Impersonation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, cookies

I'm working on a ASP.Net application where i'm planing to implement feature where the admin of the app can impersonate user and use the application as that user. If someone have an idea or experience with this will be very helpful. BTW can i use cookies to store the impersonate user data and retrieve it to the application.

Thanks a lot.

**Update**
I found this solution http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/user-impersonation-with-asp-net-identity-2/ for my project but now i'm facing some other issues. Here is also a sample from the code where I'm getting error.

```
 public async Task ImpersonateUserAsync(string userName)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;

        var originalUsername = context.User.Identity.Name;

        var impersonatedUser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);

        var impersonatedIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(impersonatedUser, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        impersonatedIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("UserImpersonation", "true"));
        impersonatedIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("OriginalUsername", originalUsername));

        var authenticationManager = context.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, impersonatedIdentity);
    }
```

The error is by this line `var authenticationManager = context.GetOwinContext().Authentication;`. Also here is the error msg.

> CS1061  C# 'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetOwinContext' and no extension method 'GetOwinContext' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'HttpContext' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any ideas what i'm missing.

Comment: this link may be help you ...https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/520341/Implement-Impersonation-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0):

The GetOwinContext extension method is located in the System.Web.Http.Owin dll which needs to be downloaded as a nuget package (The nuget package name is Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/install-nuget